# Audit operations with a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a trigger that fires in certain conditions, and when I update some data in `EMPLOYEES table` (specifically when `inserting`, `deleting` and `updating` `comm_pct` and `salary`) the changes that were made are registered into the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "HR"."AUDIT_E" ("USR" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) DEFAULT USER,
    "DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    "DML_TYPE"  VARCHAR2), -- UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
    "OLD_EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER, 
"OLD_FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2,  
...,--more fields
"OLD_JOB_ID" VARCHAR2, 
"OLD_SALARY" NUMBER, 
"OLD_COMMISSION_PCT" NUMBER,  
"NEW_FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2, 
..., -- more fields!
"NEW_JOB_ID" VARCHAR2, 
"NEW_SALARY" NUMBER, 
"NEW_COMMISSION_PCT" NUMBER)
```

My question is: How can I do an `INSERT` in `AUDIT_E` (Because I must register old and new values into it) when `updating rows` with another values (as `email` with `comm_pct` and other fields, besides only updating `comm_pct` and `salary`)? Because my trigger has the following structure:

```
IF DELETING THEN
--some actions
-- Insert into AUDIT_E(...) values...
ELSIF INSERTING THEN
    --some actions
-- Insert into AUDIT_E(...) values...
ELSIF UPDATING ('a field') THEN --I have two of these
    --some actions
-- Insert into AUDIT_E(...) values...comm_pct/salary
```

Thank you very much if you can help me and sorry for my english.

EDIT: My trigger runs fine registring changes into `audit_e`  when I am `inserting`, `deleting` rows and `updating` only `comm_pct` and `salary`:

```
AUDIT_E:
ID |Oper|Old_Name|Old_job_id|Old_comm_pct|Old_Salary|New_name|New_job_id|New_comm_pct|New_salary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |Ins |  NULL  | NULL     |  NULL      |   NULL   |Kappa   | SA_REP   | 0.2        | 4980 
2  |Upd | Kappa  | SA_REP   | 0.2        | 4980     | NULL   | NULL     | 0.3        | NULL
3  |Upd | Kappa  | SA_REP   | 0.3        | 4980     | NULL   | NULL     | NULL       | 5000
4  |Del | Kappa  | SA_REP   | 0.3        | 4980     | NULL   | NULL     | NULL       | NULL
```

But when I am changing the job_id for example (putting an additional elsif update), the changes are saved into audit_e wrong:

```
AUDIT_E:
ID |Oper|Old_Name|Old_job_id|Old_comm_pct|Old_Salary|New_name|New_job_id|New_comm_pct|New_salary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |Upd |Kappa   | SA_REP   | 0.2        | 4980     | NULL   | NULL     | NULL        | NULL
```

And I want those changes saved into audit_e table like this:

```
 AUDIT_E:
ID |Oper|Old_Name|Old_job_id|Old_comm_pct|Old_Salary|New_name|New_job_id|New_comm_pct|New_salary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |Upd |Kappa   | SA_REP   | 0.2        | 4980     | NULL   | IT_PROG  | NULL       | NULL
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand the question that you're asking.  The trigger outline you've posted doesn't seem to be valid-- if you really have `ELSIF` clauses, then you wouldn't want all the `END IF`'s.  If you want to have multiple `IF` statements, you'd keep the `END IF`'s and replace the `ELSIF`'s with `IF`'s.  But I don't believe that's the question you're asking.

Comment: I corrected the code that I posted. My idea is having an historial table (in this case AUDIT_E) that registers all the values that are changed with INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in employees table. But my problem is that I want to register my changes that aren't only changing values of salary or comm_pct or adding or dleting rows in employees

Comment: The triggers are on the EMPLOYEES table, aren't they? If they are, you have all the data, you want to store in AUDIT_E, at hand, don't you?

Comment: The trigger is executing onto employees. but I want to store data into audit_e. I can store data when I insert a row, when I deleted a row and when I update comm_pct and/or salary. But I want my trigger to register (in audit_e) other changes made in employees (like changing job_id, first_name, etcetera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure that I understand the question.  My guess is that you just want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO audit_e( dml_type, 
                       old_employee_id, new_employee_id,
                       old_first_name, new_first_name,
                       ...
                     )
    VALUES( CASE WHEN deleting 
                 THEN 'D'
                 WHEN inserting 
                 THEN 'I'
                 WHEN updating
                 THEN 'U'
                 ELSE 'X'
             END,
            :old.employee_id, :new.employee_id,
            :old.first_name, :new.first_name,
            ...
           );
END;
```

That said, it's not clear to me why you would bother storing the old and new data in your audit table each time.  The `old_*` values are always going to be identical to the `new_` values from the prior row.  It generally makes sense to just store the `new_` values in the audit table.

Comment: Yes, I need something similar to that, but only in the update case. I thought that adding  another ELSIF clause and an INSERT of values I could register my changes that I wanted to. But when I change some values that aren't comm_pct and salary( for example job_id), my audit table does not register those change correctly (the :old value is right, but the :new value remains as null in the table) if I put that block in my code.

Comment: @RyuukoMatoi - Then I'm still not understanding the question you're trying to ask.  In my answer, there are no `IF` statements in the trigger and every modification would log all the old and new values.  If that is not your goal, then I don't understand the question-- can you edit your question to include a reproducible test case that shows exactly what you want to happen?

Comment: Now I edited my question explaining with more detail my desired results. And I am very sorry for having a bad english. I hope you can understand what I want to do.

Comment: @RyuukoMatoi - How does the results of the trigger I posted differ from the results you want?  My trigger has 0 'IF' statements.  If you want to complicate your life, you can add an 'Elsif' for every column that can be updated.  I don't see any reason to do that, however.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but my trigger is a BEFORE INSERT UPDATE DELETE. And well, when I am updating comm_pct and salary, the values must keep some conditions of the trigger. I will try to do something similar and view how it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: @RyuukoMatoi - Unless you are changing the data that is being stored in the `employees` table in the trigger, there is no difference between a row-level before trigger and a row-level after trigger.  The trigger I posted would work exactly the same as a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` trigger.  Why do you believe that you need all the `ELSIF` branches?  Are you doing something special when some columns change that you don't want to do when other columns change?

Comment: Well yesterday I was working in my solution and I now know that using  more elsif clauses  was a bad idea. And thanks for the info about how it works. But now I have a question about the syntax of the insert clause. I put a CASE statement in it, but it  give me a syntax error in the VALUES part:

`VALUES
   (USER, SYSDATE, 
    CASE 
      WHEN INSERTING THEN 'INSERT' -- here's the error
      WHEN DELETING THEN 'DELETE'
      WHEN UPDATING THEN ' UPDATE'
    END CASE,
    :OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID, ... `

Comment: It was a syntax error, but I had to do anorher thing to solve it. Thanks